# How do I fix my R code for an ARIMA model, I keep receiving a error: plot.new() : figure margins?

Tags: r, error-handling

Every time I try to plot any ARIMA, AR, or MA model I get this error:

`error: plot.new() : figure margins too large.`

Here is my code:

```
x=arima.sim(n = 200, list(ma = c(0.8)), sd = 1)

plot(x)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: try setting your margins first like `par(mar = c(5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1))` and then do plot.

Comment: If you are working with rstudio just make the windows larger.